# Read the whole file and send it via sockets

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, winsock, winsock2

I made a server and client that should transfer files.
I tried to make it read the whole file and send it.
But now as I see it, I am having a problem.
Server should automatically send the file when the client is connected.
But the file is empty, and I don't know where the problem is
You can see that I'm trying to send .txt file. But I would like in the future send a big file, but not bigger than 1MB.)

Edit:

Picture here: http://img819.imageshack.us/img819/8259/aadi.jpg

- Left side: The file that I tried to send.
- Right side: The file I received

[image]

The Problem: The file that I received has been damaged, and I can't use it.

Server:

```
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#define Port 6000

SOCKET Socket, Sub;
WSADATA Winsock;
sockaddr_in Addr;
sockaddr_in IncomingAddress;
int AddressLen = sizeof(IncomingAddress);

int main()
{
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &Winsock);    // Start Winsock

    if(LOBYTE(Winsock.wVersion) != 2 || HIBYTE(Winsock.wVersion) != 2)    // Check version
    {
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }

    Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    ZeroMemory(&Addr, sizeof(Addr));
    Addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    Addr.sin_port = htons(Port);  
    bind(Socket, (sockaddr*)&Addr, sizeof(Addr));

    if(listen(Socket, 1) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("listening error\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("listening ok\n");
    }

    if(Sub = accept(Socket, (sockaddr*)&IncomingAddress, &AddressLen))
    {
        char *ClientIP = inet_ntoa(IncomingAddress.sin_addr);
        int ClientPort = ntohs(IncomingAddress.sin_port);
        printf("Client conncted!\n");
        printf("IP: %s:%d\n", ClientIP, ClientPort);

        printf("Sending file .. \n");

        FILE *File;
        char *Buffer;
        unsigned long Size;

        File = fopen("C:\\Prog.rar", "rb");
        if(!File)
        {
            printf("Error while readaing the file\n");
            getchar();
            return 0;
        }

        fseek(File, 0, SEEK_END);
        Size = ftell(File);
        fseek(File, 0, SEEK_SET);

        Buffer = new char[Size];

        fread(Buffer, Size, 1, File);
        char cSize[MAX_PATH];
        sprintf(cSize, "%i", Size);

        fclose(File);
        send(Sub, cSize, MAX_PATH, 0); // File size

        //int len = Size;
        //char *data = Buffer;

        int Offset = 0;
        while(Size > Offset)
        {
            int Amount = send(Sub, Buffer + Offset, Size - Offset, 0);

            if(Amount <= 0)
            {
                cout << "Error: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                Offset += Amount;
                printf("2\n");
            }
        }


        free(Buffer);
        closesocket(Sub);
        closesocket(Socket);
        WSACleanup();
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Client:

```
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

SOCKET Socket;
WSADATA Winsock;
sockaddr_in Addr;
int Addrlen = sizeof(Addr);

int main()
{
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &Winsock);    // Start Winsock

    if(LOBYTE(Winsock.wVersion) != 2 || HIBYTE(Winsock.wVersion) != 2)    // Check version
    {
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }

     Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    ZeroMemory(&Addr, sizeof(Addr));    // clear the struct
    Addr.sin_family = AF_INET;    // set the address family
    Addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    Addr.sin_port = htons(6000);    // set the port

    if(connect(Socket, (sockaddr*)&Addr, sizeof(Addr)) < 0)
    {
        printf("Connection failed !\n");
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Connection successful !\n");

    printf("Receiving file .. \n");



    int Size;
    char *Filesize = new char[1024];

    if(recv(Socket, Filesize, 1024, 0)) // File size
    {
        Size = atoi((const char*)Filesize);
        printf("File size: %d\n", Size);
    }

    char *Buffer = new char[Size];

    //int len = Size;
    //char *data = Buffer;

    int Offset = 0;
    while(Size > Offset)
    {
        int Amount = recv(Socket, Buffer + Offset, Size - Offset, 0);

        if(Amount <= 0)
        {
            cout << "Error: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            Offset += Amount;
            printf("2\n");
        }
    }

    FILE *File;
    File = fopen("Prog.rar", "wb");
    fwrite(Buffer, 1, Size, File);
    fclose(File);

    getchar();
    closesocket(Socket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the file size encoded as a 1,024 byte string? Or a `MAX_PATH` byte string? And what happens if the first `recv` gets, say, 31 bytes? You implemented a sane protocol for sending the file data, but you forgot to be similarly careful about how you send the file size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `send` API may not send all the data you requested to send. So, you have to pay attention to the return value, and retry the send from where the last send ended. As an example:

```
offset = 0;
while (offset < bufsize) {
    r = send(socket, buf+offset, bufsize-offset);
    if (r <= 0) break;
    offset += r;
}
```

While you are doing something similar for your file transfer, you do not make sure this is the case for your file size.

When you send the file size, you only need to send the string that represents the size, not the entire `MAX_PATH`. The receiver then needs to parse the first string to determine the size, but any data read in after the end of the first string needs to be considered part of the file. However, since you are trying the send `MAX_PATH`, the receiver should receive the same amount. Your client code receives 1024 bytes, but there is no indication this is the same size as `MAX_PATH`.

The `recv` API may also return fewer bytes than requested. You use a loop to handle reading the file, but you may need a loop to read the entire message that contains the file size.

In your client receive loop, you are incrementing the `data` pointer. This makes it unusable to write out the file later. You already have `Buffer` though, so use that to write out your file.

```
fwrite(Buffer, 1, len, File);
```

If you encounter an error doing socket I/O, you can retrieve the error with `WSAGetLastError()`, or you can issue `getsockopt()` on the socket with the `SO_ERROR` option. These may return different values, but the error reason should be correlated.

Comment: You mean like that ? fwrite((const char*)ReceivedFile, 1, len, File); ? (ReceviedFile = data after the while) But I get in the downloaded file random letter. and the rest just spaces .. I did the while you gave me in the recv and the send ..

Comment: Checked the while, and for some reason its goes to the "Amount <= 0" don't know why .. in the client and the server ..

Comment: Server Error : 10057, Client Error: 0

Comment: @user2112317: I'm not a windows developer, so you will have to lookup the server error in the appropriate manual pages. The client error just means that there was no more data to be read.

Comment: About the error its was my mistake, I was trying to send the file to the 'Socket' and not to the 'Sub'. the I edited the sources code. and I need help with my last problem: The file that I received has been damaged, and I can't use it.

Comment: Are you sure `MAX_PATH` has the same value as `1024`?

Comment: i think MAX_PATH is 256 in windows.

Answer (score 0):

Myself faced the same problem and after googling found that send() api  can send a maximum data based on low level TCP buffers which are os dependent.So inorder to send a huge file we need to perform file chunking , ie send the file in the form of chunks.

```
`const int FILE_CHUNK_SIZE = 2000; 

 //get file size
 ifstream file("myFile.file", ios::binary);
 file.seekg(0, ios::end);
 unsigned int fileSize = file.tellg();
 file.close();

 //get the file
 char* fileBuffer = new char[fileSize];
 file.open("myFile.file", ios::binary);
 file.seekg (0, ios::beg);
 file.read (fileBuffer, fileSize);
 file.close();

 //send file in chunks
 unsigned int bytesSent = 0;
 int bytesToSend = 0;

 while(bytesSent < fileSize)
 {
     if(fileSize - bytesSent >= FILE_CHUNK_SIZE)
        bytesToSend = FILE_CHUNK_SIZE;
    else
        bytesToSend = fileSize - bytesSent;
    send(ConnectSocket, fileBuffer + bytesSent, bytesToSend, 0 );
    bytesSent += bytesToSend;
}
delete [] fileBuffer;`
```

At the receiving end we need to have a recv() api called till the whole file content is read.

credits to:shacktar cplusplus.com